# Android passing View as argument

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that calls a date-picker. I need to pass a text-view to the picker, so I can change it is text value from there.

How can it be done,
Thanks

Comment: Post the code you have so far. The question is too broad.

Comment: You don't need to pass view to date picker. In fact, the date picker fragment has a method named `onDateSelected()` which can be used to set date on `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

You can not change a view's parent inside of a datepicker fragment. //Its possible but, its more hard, and take more time...

When you choose a date on the date fragment, a method is called on parent activity "onDateSelected()".

Override this method and change the TextView inside of.